# React native - Align image vertically and horizontally

Tags: react-native, jsx

In my react native application, I created a screen to show a certain list and in the flat list I configured a "renderEmpty" method to show an image in place of the list when the list is not empty. I was able to align the image horizontally, but not be able to align it vertically. What am I doing wrong? I would like your help to achieve this vertical alignment

Follow the code below:

```
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
    FlatList,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Text,
    Image
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

    const list = [];

    const renderEmpty = () => (
        <View style={styles.emptyListContainer}>
            <Image
                source={require('./assets/empty-list.png')}
                style={styles.emptyListImage}
            />
            <Text style={styles.emptyListText}>No content</Text>
        </View>
    );    

    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.listItem}>
                <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.item}>{item.nome}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }    


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          style={{flex:1}}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          data={list}
          renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem({item})}
          ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop:15,
    },
    listItem:{
        elevation: 5,
        width:"95%",
        margin: 3,
        marginBottom: 7,
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf:"center",
        flexDirection:"row",
        borderRadius:5
    },
    itemContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    item: {
        color: 'black',
        fontWeight: "800", 
        fontSize: 24,
        fontFamily: 'helvetica'
    },    
    emptyListContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    emptyListImage: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
    emptyListText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 20,
    }       
});
```

The code is available at https://snack.expo.dev/d7HXkFB3c

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FlatList needs the following prop

```html
<FlatList
  style={{flex:1}}
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} // new! can also be flex: 1 in your case
  // but flexGrow also takes care of the "list snaps back on scroll" issue
  ...
```

FlatLists are built on top of ScrollViews.  ScrollViews contain two Views: an outer View and and inner one that holds the content (contentContainer).  The `style` prop styles the outer View; `contentContainerStyle` styles the inner View.  Your inner view didn't know to fill the space of the outer view.

You can read more about contentContainerStyle here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle